# ASP.NET Core Linux. Публикация

Tags: c#, linux, nginx, asp.net-core

Опубликовал приложение на Linux Ubuntu. Приложение работает нормально. Но после определенного времени оно отключается. И nginx выводит ошибку `502 Bad Gateway`.

В чем может быть проблема? Или так и должно быть?
Можно ли заставить приложение работать постоянно?

Новичок в Linux, если что.

Comment: То есть вы что то где то запустили и оно как то почему то не работает. Думаю, стоит добавить деталей в вопрос, так как сейчас можно считать что вы ничего не написали.

Comment: Приложение работает. Но оно отключается через определенное время. Я не могу понять причину. Приходится перезапускать вручную.

Comment: Это все уже написано выше. Как дела с логами? Что ваше приложение вообще делает? Падает приложение или реверс прокся? Сами что то пытались понять про ошибку?

Comment: Насчет логов, посмотреть не могу, т.к. соединение разрывается через определенное время (выводит ошибку `client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer`), приходится авторизироваться снова. Насчет того, что делает приложение, даже пустой проект mvc падает через определенное время. Падает само приложение. И приходится запускать снова командой `dotnet ***.dll`.

Comment: Не понял, почему логи не можете глянуть, они не в файлы у вас пишутся?

Comment: Пытался искать решение. Нашел что-то про автозапуск. Но не думаю, что дело в этом. Если не ошибаюсь, это нужно для последующего запуска приложения после запуска сервера. Думаю, сервер не может перезапускаться через несколько минут.

Comment: Обычно я получаю информацию об ошибках в консоли.

Comment: Пишите логи в файлы и смотрите, что там за ошибки

Comment: Без логов вы вряд ли что-то узнаете точно, стоит поучиться их находить и уметь читать. Также непонятно, как вы публиковали - классическая схема подразумевает, что приложение демонизируется и работает постоянно. https://habr.com/en/post/332920/